# How to get nagios to return free diskspace

Tags: linux, nagios

I'm having troubles with my nagios getting it to give me feedback about the ammount of free/used diskspace on the clients it's monitoring.

at the moment, it runs the default `check_all_disks!20%!10%` and one `check_disk!20%!10%!/`

Only thing it shows me on the "Service Detail" overview is: `Disk OK`

It would be very nice to have either the percentage or free/used in the service detail overview.

Is this possible?

If I click the service check - it shows me some numbers in Performance Data. 
What's this supposed to be?

Edit: Seems like when updating to the newest version of Nagios Core - the information I was looking for, gets displayed.

Comment: I am getting full details for the check_disk commands. What is your nagios version? Can you post the defined check command and the plugin version?

Comment: It's reporting to be Nagios® Core™ 3.2.0
- How do I check the plugins version?

Comment: You can use `check_disk --help`. You may need to specify the full path to check_disk such as `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk`.

Comment: Plugins: check_disk v1.4.14 (nagios-plugins 1.4.14)

Comment: Same of mine! What do you get if you run the command manually like `/usr/lib/nagios/plugin/check_disk -w 20% -c 10%`?

Comment: If I run the command manually - it gives me the output I want! 
 `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /` ->
`DISK OK - free space: / 97772 MB (95% inode=96%);| /=4793MB;86443;97248;0;108054
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After upgrading the nagios core to the newest version - it reports free disk space just the way I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

I am using this [check_snmp_storage](http://nagios.manubulon.com/snmp_storage.html), It's mandatory for it to work that the servers you are querying have enabled snmp, but it will give you percentage reports for every mounted partition on your system.

Really nice and effortless

Also on the snmdp.conf i add:
    disk / 10%

To have a warning level set to default (in case you monitor it with cacti)

Comment: This is definitly a workaround worth taking a note of! Will consider it if all else fails :)